# Slow growth and constant premature flowering of pepper plants

Tags: growth, flowering, capsicum

My potted capsicum plants are growing very slowly. I had topped off the plants due to flower buds appearing in saplings but the buds are appearing again in the side branches of the leaf nodes. What should I do?

Location: Delhi, India

[image: 17 days ago]
17 days ago

[image: Today]
Today

Comment: How much sunlight do they get?

Comment: Due to winters and pollution the intensity is a bit less. Otherwise they're on the terrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The early formation of flowers and fruits we would generally interpret as stress in the plants for one reason or another. It might be temperature, lack of air at the roots, lack of light, room for roots to grow, too acid or alkaline conditions for growth, unbalanced fertilizer, or external chemicals such as fungicides. In your location it is unlikely to be light or temperature which is causing the stress. If we look at your plants they seem okay, except that the leaves are not the bright green we would look for and rather small in size unless small leaves are characteristic of your pepper variety. Your plants do seem rather crowded in their pot - one single pepper in that size of pot might do a lot better.

At a guess, it is probably root room that is the issue here. If the pot is shallow then the roots will quickly run out of space to grow and it will switch to non-vegetative growth, sensing that its resources will soon be exhausted. However it is not too late for action; if you can find some other pots and good fresh soil break apart the peppers and give them each one good pot with room to grow substantial roots with good drainage to ensure that the water does not accumulate in the soil. This would almost certainly reduce their stress.

Comment: Pot dimensions are- 12 inch upper diameter, 11 inch height, 9 inch soil height, 8 inch lower diameter. Leaf width is 4 cm biggest, 3 cm average.

Comment: I uprooted the plants from the pot and it appears that the roots are mainly around 3 cm of each plant only, with just two three hairs stretching quite a bit away in all. The soil's very damp and pretty wet at the lower end. So I have repotted the plants in 4 inch pots till they get healthy and the plants get root bound. Then I will repot in bigger pots. Is this okay?

Comment: Good move, moist, not wet.